# drop down selection page reload function for multiple variables

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I am working on a piece of code that will display the content of a mysql query in a template, since the query could feasibly return hundreds of results Ive included a page limiter and navigation tool. Unfortunately I am having a problem passing the page number after I select the number of results to show per page. The page nav is separate and working fine except it cant see the page number once this function has run.

```
<script>
function refreshpage(results_per_page){
window.location="classifieds.php?&results_per_page="+results_per_page
}
</script>

<?php
$results_per_page = $_GET['results_per_page'];   

?>
<select onchange="refreshpage(this.value);">
<option selected value="<?php echo $results_per_page?>"><?php echo $results_per_page?></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

The above code works fine and automatically reloads the page, but when ever i try to introduce a $page variable the pageRefresh function fails to work. Is this the right way to go about what I am after or is there another way that will let me include another variable. All it needs to be is;

```
$page;
```

taken from the url

```
 $page = $_GET['page'];
```

Ive tried sending it with the onchange function, calling it from within the refreshPage Function, even using an intermediate function to assemble an extension with all the relevant data and nothing seems to give the result.

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks to sasse, I got enough Info to correct the code I believe. This seems to now work so if anyone else has had this issue, this seems to be a good work around. Thanks! (never occurred to me to use val!)

```
<script>
function refreshpage(results_per_page){
var page = <?php echo $_GET['page'] ?>;
window.location="classifieds.php?page=" + page + "&results_per_page="+results_per_page
}
</script>

<?php
$results_per_page = $_GET['results_per_page'];   

?>
<select onchange="refreshpage(this.value);">
<option selected value="<?php echo $results_per_page?>"><?php echo $results_per_page?></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling the "refreshPage" with onchange for the "select"-element and sending "this.value" you will send the selected value to the method.

Therefore you will send 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 to the refreshPage method as parameter "results_per_page".

I would think you don't want one result per page, but I might be wrong.

When are you setting either "results_per_page" or "page"? My thought was that the "select"-element was for the "page" attribute and therefore the method "refreshPage" should accept "page" as parameter.

I'll write some code to demonstrate my intention.

```
<script>
function refreshpage(page){
    var results_per_page = <?php echo $_GET['results_per_page'] ?>;
    window.location="classifieds.php?page=" + page + "&results_per_page="+results_per_page
}
</script>

<select onchange="refreshpage(this.value);">
<!-- If this select is for "page" then I don't understand this next line -->
<option selected value="<?php echo $results_per_page?>"><?php echo $results_per_page?></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

If the case is that I didn't understand correctly then tell me what I thought wrong and I'll update my answer. And also, update your question with what you've tried so far as long as the "page" goes, when is it set? Do you have a "next" and a "previous" button?

Comment: sorry If I was unclear, The page selection function is a separate function that takes its info from the URl of a loaded page. This is a side function to reload the URl with specific info . The select section is for results per page. It is set to the numbers 1-5 as this is my sample data and I need to make sure the other functions accept the code before using thousands of data sets. The Functions Variable is just for "results_per_page". the $page variable is taken from the URL of the page and isnt something selectable with this code.

Comment: Anyone here who understands Stackoverflow better than me? Should I now update my answer even though OP already got his answer done himself with helf from my code or should he accept my answer as correct since it helped him find the correct answer for his solution?

Comment: your answer was correct, just using the wrong variable, thats all :)